# Starting short-end OIS zero curve building

Tags: interest-rate-swap, ois-discounting, ois

I understand the concept of bootstrapping and building the curve when we have the values for first few maturities. However, I can't quite get how the initial values for zero curve rates are derived from tradable instruments. As I understand, these values are directly implied from OIS par rates.

Can someone please clarify, how, given, say a 1M OIS swap bid and ask, can I get the zero curve point at 1M maturity?

Answer (score 2):

I think I figured it out. The problem was with day count conventions.

OIS par rate bid/ask are quoted in 360/ACT form, while zero curve rates are universalized to ACT/ACT (or whatever else is desired by the end user). Therefore, to get the zero rates, mid price of OIS swap is used to find the discount factor as 1/(1+r)^t(360/ACT) from which then zero rate r0 can be backed out 1/(1+r0)^t(ACT/ACT). So, they are essentially same thing, with a desired day count adjustment.